# Issue with head() command when following a machine learning textbook in python

Tags: python, command

I am following along Machine Learning by Aurelein Geron. I am having issues accessing the data using Jupyter notebook and the `head` command. It returns error file not found. Thanks for the help!

```
    def fetch_housing_data(housing_url = HOUSING_URL, housing_path = HOUSING_PATH):
        os.makedirs(housing_path, exist_ok = True)
        tgz_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.tgz")
        housing_tgz = tarfile.open(tgz_path)
        housing_tgz.extractall(path=housing_path)
        housing_tgz.close()  

  
    def load_housing_data(housing_path = HOUSING_PATH):
            fetch_housing_data()
            csv_path = os.path.join(housing_path,"housing.csv")
            return pd.read_csv(csv_path)
    
    
    housing = load_housing_data()
    housing.head()
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your post a bit. Thanks

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
We expect a minimal working example of the problem, including appropriate code to trace the internal operation.

Comment: Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; your posting must be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.  Since you haven't properly supplied your code, error, and tracing attempts, we have no way to help you.

Comment: @gradycool does this help?

Comment: From the screen shot you first posted to this code, you added the line `fetch_housing_data()`. Does it still not work?

Comment: It still does not work with the fetch_housing_data() in there

Comment: it says datasets\\housing\\housing.tgz cannot be found

Answer (score 0):

Use this function for `load_housing_data()`:

```
def load_housing_data(housing_path = HOUSING_PATH):
    fetch_housing_data()
    csv_path = os.path.join(housing_path, 'housing.csv')
    return pd.read_csv(csv_path)
```

The author made a mistake in which he didn't call the `fetch_housing_data`.
You can check my [notebook](https://github.com/adhadse/colab_repo/blob/b0b586d65a5730bd05462055f71c3afe5c667af3/homl/Ch%202%20End-to-End%20Machine%20Learning%20Project.ipynb) , as I am also reading the same.